# Uncaught type error in JS, cannot set props of null using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror, draw

I am trying to generate image using specific coordinates on HTML

```
class Car {
    constructor(id, image, vPosition, wins, hPosition, finishedRace) { //there is a chance I may need to remove the last 3 parms (wins,hpos and finished race)
        this.id = id;
        this.image = image;
        this.vPosition = vPosition;
        this.hPosition = hPosition;
        this.finishedRace = finishedRace;
        this.wins = wins;
    }
```

Thats my constructor of object car (I am not posting getters and setters since they work fine and are not relevant to my problem)

```
draw() {
        return "<img id='"+this.id+"' src='"+this.image+"' width='250px' style='position: absolute; left: "+this.hPosition+"px; top: "+this.vPosition+"px;' />";
    }
```

that is my draw method which I plan to use to draw car objects to HTML

```
testFunction();

function testFunction() {
    document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = car1.draw();
};
```

This is test function where I am trying to render the first car object on HTML but that doesn't work (all of this is wrapped under window.onload)

```
<body>
<h1><b>Race</b></h1>

<p>
    <input id="startRace" type="button" value="Start Race" />
    <input id="resetRace" type="button" value="Reset Race" />
    <input id="viewStats" type="button" value="View Statistics" />
</p>

<div class="1">
   

   
    </div>
    <div class="vl"></div> -->
</div>
```

Thats my HTML code.
The error i get is : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')

Comment: I think the issue is that you are getting the element by ID, but you used a class. So, use document.querySelector(".1") and that should resolve your issue.

Comment: it still gives the same error @alonealgorithm

Comment: Aye i got it! I changed html to id instead of class and .1 doesn't work but 1 works! Thanks tho cause you pointed me in the right direction